# python list comprehension for multiple return function to numpy array

Tags: python, list, numpy, tuples

From this thread we can see, how to unpack multiple return values from list comprehension to a tuple.

```
def f(x):
  return 2*x, x*x

x = range(1, 4)
xlist, ylist = zip(*[f(value) for value in x])
```

Is there a way to do this straight to a numpy array? Or is the only solution to to this with:

```
xlist = np.asarray(xlist)
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```
xlist,ylist = np.fromiter(
        itertools.chain.from_iterable(f(value) for value in x),
        dtype=np.int_,
        count=len(x)*2
    ).reshape((-1,2)).T
```

or

```
xlist,ylist = np.array([f(value) for value in x]).T
```

However, the approaches directly working on arrays, as proposed by the other answers, could be more readable and would be also faster.

Comment: Why is the first solution almost twice as fast?

Comment: @Peterhack just to be sure, do you mean faster than the other solution I proposed? Its probably because it does not create the intermediate list, the output array is pre-allocated using the `count` argument and directly filled using the values from the generator (to make it clear: there is no list comprehension involved in the first solution but a generator expression).

Answer (score 2):

To do this with a `numpy.array`, simply pass the argument as an array itself. The operations in the function get mapped over the array argument and a tuple of two arrays is returned:

```
>>> xlist, ylist = f(np.asarray(x))
>>> xlist
array([2, 4, 6])
>>> ylist
array([1, 4, 9])
```

Comment: I am aware of that, but this was more ore less just a basic example. That is why I am still interested in such solution. E.g. what would happen if I want the last result to be the input of the next iteration. Like: `import numpy as np
x = np.arange(10, 14)
y = []
t = 0
for j, i in enumerate(x):
    t += i
    y.append(t)`

Comment: That is why I did not ask for that. I just wanted to see how this works, independently of whether the function can handle arrays or not. Sorry for not making that clear.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `zip` or list comprehensions. You also don't need to change your `f` function:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(1, 4)
>>> array1, array2 = f(x)
>>> array1
array([2, 4, 6])
>>> array2
array([1, 4, 9])
```

If `x` is an array, `2 * x` means that each element of `x` will be multiplied by `2`:

```
>>> 2 * x
array([2, 4, 6])
```

Comment: Assuming there is something in between the function that cannot handle arrays, the list comprehension would be the way to got, right? That is why I was looking for that acutally.